# Android - Autoscale TextView height depending to text

Tags: android, textview, height, scale

I want that a TextView height automatically rezises depending on how much text it contains.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="COOK COMMENT"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/longtext"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When for example the textView2 should be auto scaled than the linearLayout height should change whit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and make sure you nest your `TextView` inside a `ScrollView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="COOK COMMENT"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/longtext"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is that I have a scrollview in the first layout and in that I have a ViewPager (github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions). I want to set the posted layout it that viewPager and to scroll the first layout (not that posted one) and so I need a TextView that changes its height depending on the text length.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the Activity that controls the view:

```
textView2.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            v.setLines(v.getLineCount());
            return true;
        }
    });
```

You can also customize the code to set a minimal or maximal height in line units.